# Can I filter an ng-repeat by more than one item at a time?

Tags: angularjs

I have this ng-repeat:

```
ng-repeat="row in phs.phrasesView = 
   (phs.phrases | keywordRange:phs.englishRange )"
```

Here's the code for the filter:

```
app.filter('keywordRange', function () {
    return function (value, english) {
        var out = [];
        if (!english) {
            return value;
        }
        var ucEnglish = english[0].toUpperCase() + english.substr(1);
        value.map((row: any) => {
            if (typeof row.english !== 'undefined' &&
                typeof row.english === 'string' &&
                row.english != null &&
                (row.english.includes(english) || row.english.includes(ucEnglish))
                ) {
                out.push(row);
            }
        });
        return out;
    };
});
```

What I would like to do is to extend this so that rows that contain:

```
phs.englishRange or phs.romajiRange
```

Are passed through the filter.

Note that only one of englishRange or romajiRange will be populated.  There won't be a case where they both have a value.

Can someone tell me is this possible and give me some advice on how I can do this?

Comment: You can pass `phs.englishRange and phs.romajiRange` like  `keywordRange:phs.englishRange: phs.romajiRange` and put your logic in filter. Is it possible?